# Asp.Net Core Multi-Tenant

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, identity, multi-tenant

I have couple question regarding the multi-tenant in asp.net core, Single DB

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<int>
{
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
    public UserStatus Status { get; set; }

    public virtual Tenant Tenant { get; set; }
}
```

for the registered account this below code it working to insert a new account.

```
var user = new ApplicationUser { VendorId = model.VendorId, UserName = model.Username, Email = model.Email, Status = UserStatus.Active };
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
```

I found an issue when implementing the Login.

```
var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Username, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
```

What is the solution for the method
PasswordSignInAsync, FindByNameAsync

since I would like to restrict by tenantId for all query of UserManager and SignInManager

Answer (score -1):

Based on my experience, you have a couple of options here

1. Either get the tenant name [Company Name] from the user as like Amazon to infer the tenant id from the use input
2. Infer the tenant id from the unique username or email id similar to Office 365 from Microsoft.
3. Incase of any user that may have access to more than one company, just allow the user to login from the primary tenant and list all the accessible tenant's in his workspace or portal or home page.

You can just try to get the user info from `Asp.Net Identity` and then validate it against the user input and also use the same to infer the tenant id or tenant context that the user is trying to login to.

HTH

Comment: Asp.Net Identity how to extend

Comment: Sorry to answer you. How do you know the tenant id while logging the user in??